# Pass template object

Tags: c++

I have a template class:

```
template <typename T>
struct FilesName{
  const T filename_A;
  const T filename_B;
  FilesName(const T& _filename_A, const T& _filename_B): 
  filename_A(_filename_A),
  filename_B(_filename_B)
  { }
};
```

The type `T` could be `std::string`, or `std::wstring`, or otrers string container.

I'd like pass it to constuctor new struct,

which `T` defined by user.

```
struct Files{
  std::ofstream file_A;
  std::ofstream file_B;
  Files(const FilesName& _FilesName) :
    file_A(_FilesName.filename_A),
    file_B(_FilesName.filename_B)
  { }
};
```

I hope user invoke above code:

```
struct FilesName<std::string> fn{"fa_name","fb_name"};
struct Files f(fn);
```

But compiler tell me

```
argument list for class template "Files" is missing
```

I modify to following can pass compile

```
template <typename T>
struct Files{
  std::ofstream file_A;
  std::ofstream file_B;
  Files(const FilesName& _FilesName) :
    file_A(_FilesName<T>.filename_A),
    file_B(_FilesName<T>.filename_B)
  { }
};
```

but user invoke code will be

```
struct FilesName<std::string> fn{"fa_name","fb_name"};
struct Files<std::string> f(fn); # Here must add <std::string>
```

it's not I desired,

because the template type of `FilesName` should be verdict before pass into `Files`.
I think I don't need to type `<std::string>` again

Has solutions?

Comment: You probably want `std::ofstream` rather than `std::ostream`.

Comment: Hi @HolyBlackCat: Oh!my bad.

Comment: Works in a c++17 compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/PPyyFJ thanks to [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: Do you want multiple types based off the `Files` template, each with a single constructor? Or do you want `Files` to be a single type with multiple constructors?

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles: Good! Please post it to answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JaMiT: Code I prefered, as *Alan Birtles* shows, I also discover other solution I post solution.

Comment: @curlywei Huh? It is tough to parse your comment, but based on the answer you posted, I take it the answer is that you want `Files` to be a single type with multiple constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also discover following code are working fine:

```
struct Files{
  std::ofstream file_A;
  std::ofstream file_B;
  template <typename T>
  Files(const FilesName<T>& _FilesName) :
    file_A(_FilesName<T>.filename_A),
    file_B(_FilesName<T>.filename_B)
  { }
};
```

Comment: Oh! I discovery. I'll fix.